# What's the proper way for calculating first quartile?

Tags: probability, statistics

How should I calculate quartiles? In a book I read (by Amir D. Aczel) it is said that:

> First quartile is th 25th percentile, that means a value for
>   which $1/4$ of oberervation's results are lower.

Shouldn't it be `lower or equal`? According to the book if I have observation like this:

$1, 3, 7, 9, 10, 11$

the value of the first quartile is on position: $(6+1)\cdot 0.25 = 1.75$, so it's $1.75$. But shouldn't it be $3$? For both $1.75$ and $3$ 25% of observations are below the given value. But that's the same for $1.25, 2.9$ and $2$. Are all answers correct?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207090/how-to-find-the-quartiles/207267#207267 please check this..

Comment: You could check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory it means the point a quarter of the way up the cumulative distribution.  In practice there are various definitions used, particularly in statistical computing.  For example in R there are [nine different definitions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html), the first three for a discrete interpretation and the rest for a variety of continuous interpolations. [Wikipedia has a tenth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Examples).

R types 1, 2, 3 and 5 give $3$ as the first quartile, as you calculated, and if you want to regard this observation as a discrete population that is indeed the obvious answer.  The other interpolations range from $2$ to $4$.

Your figure of $1.75$ looks wrong and it is unclear how you calculated it: if it supposed to be a weighted average of $1$ and $3$ then perhaps you were trying to get $1 \times \frac14 + 3 \times \frac34 = 2.5$, which is what R type 6 would produce. Or perhaps you were trying something else.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it. You are right - it should be $2.5$, not $1.75$ according to the method I was trying to use.